# How to make my circle appear with classes and mouseclicks?

Tags: class, javafx, canvas, methods, scenebuilder

I am new to JavaFx and i am making a simple drawing program where i draw shapes. The problem i am having now is that i dont know how to make the circle appear on the screen when i click on the screen. So first I want to press a button that says "Circle" and then when i click on the canvas i want it to spawn. (I am switching between scenebuilder and intellij btw).

This is some of my program:

Classes:

```
public abstract class Shape {

    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;

    public Color color = Color.WHITE;


    public void creatingShapes(double x, double y, int width, int height) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {

        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public abstract void draw(GraphicsContext g);

}
```

public class Circle extends Shape {

```
@Override
```

public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {

```
g.setFill(color);
g.fillOval(200,200,200,200);
g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
g.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
g.strokeOval(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
```

====================================================

Controller class:

public class HelloController {

```
@FXML
private Button logoutButton;
@FXML
private BorderPane scenePane;

Stage stage;

@FXML
private ColorPicker myColorPicker;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> myChoiceBox;

@FXML
private Button circle;
@FXML
private GraphicsContext g;

private final Shape[] shapes = new Shape[500];

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(310,333);

boolean drawShape = true;
int count = 0;
private final Color currentColor = Color.BLUE;

private final String[] menuAlternatives = {"Sparning", "Testing?", "Exit?"};

public void onCircleClicked() {

    circle.setOnAction((event) -> addShape(new Circle()));



}



//skapa shapes
public void addShape(Shape shape) {

    shape.setColor(currentColor);
    shape.creatingShapes(10,10,150,100);
    shapes[count] = shape;
    count++;
    paintCanvas();
}


public void changeColor(ActionEvent event) {


    Color myColor = myColorPicker.getValue();
    scenePane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(myColor, null, null)));



}


public void initialize() {

    g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();


}
public void paintCanvas() {

    g.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
    Arrays.stream(shapes, 0, count).forEach(s -> s.draw(g));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Placing a circle on canvas with mouse event**

[image: spawning in canvas javafx]

From [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#fillOval-double-double-double-double-)

> public void fillOval(double x,
> double y,
> double w,
> double h)
>
> Fills an oval using the current fill paint.
> This method will be affected by any of the global common or fill attributes
> as specified in the Rendering Attributes Table.
>
> Parameters:
>
> x - the X coordinate of the upper left bound of the oval.
>
> y - the Y coordinate of the upper left bound of the oval.
>
> w - the width at the center of the oval.
>
> h - the height at the center of the oval.

As we can see x and y params from `fillOval()` will put the circle at the left upper corner of its bound . to spawn at its very center , we need to subtract half widht and half height to x and y coordinates given by mouseclick event.

this is a single class javafx app you can try

**App.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


 public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(640, 480);
        GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {

            double x = e.getX();
            double y = e.getY();           
            context.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
            context.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            context.fillOval(x - 20, y - 20, 40, 40);
            context.strokeOval(x - 20, y - 20, 40, 40);
        });

        var scene = new Scene(new Group(canvas), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("spawn with mouse click");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can i implement my circle class in the "canvas.setonmouseclicked" so the method doesnt have much code in it?